# Uso de regexp_replace para ocultar informacion sensible

Tags: regex, oracle-12c

Actualmente estoy intentando utilizar la funcion ***regexp_replace*** para ocultar información dentro de una consulta para un campo que guarda información alfa-numérica. El resultado que espero es: Sin importar la longitud del campo se remplacen por **#** todos los caracteres exceptuando los últimos cuatro; por ejemplo:

```
IDENTIFICACION  | RESULTADO
AU966R98        | ####6R98
1095764235      | ######4235
SSN945          | ##N945
```

Hasta el momento he realizado el siguiente QUERY:

```
SELECT identification , regexp_replace(identification,'(.+)(....)','#\2') REDACTIONI FROM clientes;
```

Pero el resultado que obtengo es:

```
IDENTIFICACION  | RESULTADO
AU966R98        | #6R98
1095764235      | #4235
SSN945          | #N945
```

¿Hay alguna forma de realizar lo mencionado utilizando unicamente expresiones regulares?

Comment: Esto se puede hacer con expresiones regulares... pero no con las limitadas expresiones regulares del `regexp_replace` de Oracle.

Answer (score 2):

No veo la forma que puedas resolverlo con `regexp_replace()`, el problema es que se detecta un patrón variable en longitud para reemplazarlo por un número fijo de caracteres `#`. Me parece mucho más sencillo, resolverlo de esta forma:

```
select lpad(substr(identification,-4), length(identification), '#')
       from clientes;
```